# Proof of Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5\cdot 2^n-4}{2^n-1}=5.$$ I have already proved this just using the definition of convergence. How do I go about proving this only using the sandwich theorem and sum/product/quotient rule?

I can divide the whole expression by $2^n$ and say the following: I know $5 - \frac4{2^n}$ tends to $5$ as $n\to\infty$. And I also know that $1 -\frac1{2^n}$ tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$ so using the quotient rule, I can say that the whole expression tends to $\frac51=5$ as $n\to\infty$. At first glance this seems correct to me. Is there a more sophisticated way of proving this?

Comment: @CameronBuie, it is $5$ not $\infty$ in the last limit, right?

Comment: Sorry my denominator was wrong, I've corrected it. Can you reread please?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Oops. Copy-paste mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Post has been corrected and kindly edited. Please reread!

Answer (score 0):

That's absolutely correct. Since for all $n$ we have $$\frac{5\cdot 2^n-4}{2^n+1}=\cfrac{5-\frac4{2^n}}{1+\frac1{2^n}},$$ where the numerator and denominator of the RHS expression converge (with the denominator converging to a non-$0$ number), then the limit of quotients is the quotient of limits, just as you've done.

Comment: Should I prove before hand how $1/2^n$ converges to 0?

Comment: That would certainly be the simplest way to show that the numerator of the RHS expression tends to $5$ and the denominator tends to $1$ (again, using the rule about quotients). It's a fairly easy proof, too. Just show that $n\le 2^n$ for all $n$ by induction, then apply Archimedean property. Or you can just use a direct $\epsilon$-$N$ argument, if you've proven the existence of logarithms.